# Javascript fetch all sub folder names from a directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a requirement like,
    I need to get all the subfolder names from a directory (provided path for that directory) using js or angular js.
for example,
  If we have directory structure like,

```
   Mainfolder     
     - subfolder1
     - subfolder2
     - subfolder3
```

If we give path for Main folder , I should be able to get subfolder names as array like `["subfolder1","subfolder2","subfolder3"]`

Please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask. HINT: Show code and effort. Anyway it is not possible on the client. Write a server process. Only other way is if you know a file in each and can test to see if you get an error on subfolder4/knownfile.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @mplungjan .I will keep your suggestion in my mind

Answer (score 0):

This kind of operation shouldn't be done via client side JavaScript. It should be a server side task, if you use node.js -

```
function getDirectories(path) {
  return fs.readdirSync(path).filter(function (file) {
    return fs.statSync(path+'/'+file).isDirectory();
  });
}
```